# In TFS Is there a way to track changes of scripts I make in sql 2008r2?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there a way for TFS to perform a profile of SQL 2008 and update all new scripts in TFS automatically?  Also what is the recommended way to keep track of changes that are made to queries in sql 2008?

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio Team Developer you could use a SQL Server project to have your tables, views, stored procedures etc. under source control with TFS.

Aside from this a common way to keep your database scripts under source control is to manually generate CREATE/UPDATE SQL scripts via SQL Server and check them into your source control structure whenever database objects have changed.

This solution of course requires disciplined developers to have always an exact duplicate of your SQL Server objects in your source control.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I am planning on creating versioned build scripts and keeping track of that in TFS.  But I need to look for some off the shelf solution in the meantime.